# ADDTIME inconsistent behaviour

Tags: mysql, timestamp

Why does the following query produce inconsistent results in the Result field?

```
SELECT 
    NOW() AS xTime, 
    FLOOR(RAND()*(99-35+1)+35) AS AddMins, 
    ADDTIME(
        (SELECT xTime), 
        CONCAT('00:', CAST((SELECT AddMins) AS CHAR))) AS Result;
```

Sometimes it returns a timestamp like this:

```
2018-08-06 15:45:16.000000
```

with 6 decimals instead of zero decimals. And sometimes it even returns:

```
null
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is not exact in MySQL.  So, if your query is doing that, you could end up with some decimal place rounding error.  If this be a problem, then you should use an exact numeric type.

Comment: How would I need to adjust my query in order to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

The following query works:

```
SELECT
    xTime,
    addMins,
    TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE, AddMins, xTime) Result
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        NOW() AS xTime, 
        FLOOR(RAND()*(99-35+1)+35) AS AddMins
) t;
```

[image]

### Demo

The problem in your original approach is your call to `ADDTIME`, using a time string such as `00:76`, which will crash the function, because you are specifying more than 60 minutes.  Instead, the closest thing might be to use `TIMESTAMPADD`, as I have used above.

Comment: I figured the minutes should've been lower than 100 (ie 00-99) instead of lower than 59. I resorted to using the `TIMESTAMPADD` as you used aswell. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It returns NULL when your minutes are more than 59, and it returns the zeroes at the end when you give it a string ending with '.000.' (no clue why though).

You can use something like this to add a random amount of minutes:

```
SELECT NOW()+ INTERVAL (FLOOR(RAND()*(99-35+1)+35)) MINUTE
```

Comment: Thank you for this approach, will give it a try if Tim's approach isn't working!